# Probability of an event when given false positive and false negative values

Tags: probability

Question: You given three methods with false negative and false positive rates for predicting a hurricane.

```
                      Method 1  Method 2    Method 3

      False Positive:   40%       50%         20%

      False Negative:   20%       10%         40%
```

Methods 1 and 3 predict a hurricane, whereas Method 2 does not predict a hurricane. What is the probability that there is a hurricane?

This question is from a college level statistics course.

I have already calculated the probabilites, and I suspect that it is Bayesian in nature, but I don't know where to proceed from here.

P(M1 | H) = 80%, P(M1 | ~H) = 40%, P(~M1 | H) = 20%, P(~M1 | ~H) = 60%

P(M2 | H) = 90%, P(M2 | ~H) = 50%, P(~M2 | H) = 10%, P(~M2 | ~H) = 50%

P(M3 | H) = 60%, P(M3 | ~H) = 20%, P(~M3 | H) = 40%, P(~M3 | ~H) = 80%

Comment: Added more info and steps taken.

Comment: holy downvotes. Well, now that context has been added, I think it's a great question.

Comment: @6005 Why don't you vote to reopen, then?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of question is actually a little controversial. You asked:

> What is the probability that there is a huricane?

What do you actually mean by this? Says the frequentist, surely, there is either going to be a hurricane or there isn't--there's no "probability" about it. The only question is, how good are our false positive and false negative rates?

But, you've asked what the probability of there being a hurricane is, so you've forced this to be a Bayesian question. Hence (and this is always the downside of Bayesian statistics), we have to choose a prior probability--if we don't, we literally cannot answer the question. Let's say before looking at the method results, you think the probability of there being a hurricane is $p$.

So now you have, by a classic application of Bayes rule,
\begin{align*}
P(H | M_1 \land \lnot M_2 \land M_3)
&= \frac{P(H) P(M_1 \land \lnot M_2 \land M_3 | H)}{P(M_1 \land \lnot M_2 \land M_3)} \\
&= \frac{P(H) P(M_1 | H) P(\lnot M_2 | H) P(M_3 | H)}{P(H) P(M_1 | H) P(M_2 | H) P(M_3 | H) + P(\lnot H) P(M_1 | \lnot H) P(\lnot M_2 | \lnot H) P(M_3 | \lnot H)}.
\end{align*}
Here we used an additional assumption--one that was not specified!--that *given* $H$ or $\lnot H$, the three experiments are independent. In fact, this is probably *not* a reasonable assumption in some real-life scenarios--it's quite possible that your three methods make use of some of the same predicting tools or make use of correlated data, in which case they will not be independent.
But anyway, let's move on.
\begin{align*}
&= \frac{(p)(.8)(.1)(.6)}{(p)(.8)(.1)(.6) + (1-p)(.4)(.5)(.2)} \\
&= \frac{48p}{48p + 40(1-p)} \\
&= \boxed{\frac{6p}{5 + p}}.
\end{align*}

Here's a picture of this.
On the $x$-axis is the original probability $p$.
The red line shows the updated probaiblity $\frac{6p}{5+p}$ once you see the results of the experiments.
The blue line is the line $y = x$, for comparison.

[image]

As you can see, this particular set of method results would not make us much more confident of there being a hurricane, if we already thought there was one, and conversely, it would not change our mind much if we already thought there was not one. It tells us the most when our prior probability was that we were close to exactly unsure ($p = \frac12$), and regardless of $p$, it does always increase the probability of there being a hurricane a little bit, since you can see the red line is above the blue line.

Had we measured three "yes"s or three "no"s from the three methods, we would have seen a much greater difference between the two lines. As it is, conflicting data does not convince us much.

Comment: Please explain the downvote, thank you!